# Predictions after Cox regression

Tags: predictive-models, cox-model

I'm new to survival analysis and will apperciate your help regarding predictions after Cox regression.

I'm running a cox model (using stata's -stcox-) in which I examine the effect of a continuous independent variable (ranges from 0 to 1) on the hazard to commit crime. The coefficient I get for this variable makes sense.
Then, I want to get predictions based on this variables. Essentiely, what I want is the predict risk to commit crime for different values of the independent variable (Is this possible?).

To this end, I used the margins command, i.e.:

```
margins, at(indep_var=(0(0.2)1)) atmeans
```

However, I struggle to understand what the values I get represent. For example, what does it mean if I get a value of 0.75, or 1.23? I don't believe it represents the hazard to commit crime.
Is there any way to get what I'm looking for?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A Cox model returns hazard *ratios*, not absolute hazards. Although that's inherent in the nature of a Cox model, it can lead to a lot of confusion. A hazard ratio must be expressed *between two conditions*.

Although I don't use Stata, its [manual on Cox models](https://www.stata.com/manuals/ststcoxpostestimation.pdf) seems to suggest that the default outcome from the `margins` command is in the *hazard ratio* scale. That presumably is the hazard ratio with respect to whatever the `stcox` routine chose as the reference set of predictor-variable values. That's another source of confusion with Cox models, as different software routines make different choices about the reference condition, choices which don't always make a lot of sense. You will have to read the Stata documentation to know what reference-condition choice `stcox` makes.

A more useful display might be to plot a set of estimated survival curves over time at your chosen values of the continuous predictor, at some representative combination of values of the other predictors.

Comment: Thanks @EdM. I will look into that. Following your answer, is it even possible to somehow get absolute hazards?

Comment: @Eran Remember that a standard survival model assumes that all individuals eventually experience the event; the question is risk at any given time. Absolute hazards ([failure rates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Failure_rate#)) change over time, except for simple exponential models. A Cox model assumes that the basic form of the baseline hazard is the same for all individuals, with hazard ratios providing a useful summary of differences associated with treatments, clinical characteristics, etc.  For a Cox model the absolute hazard is exactly 0 between event times.